# How to get model map value to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp

I need to get response value to jquery for validate that

this is my Jsp Code

```
<p class="booking-desc custom-padding">${selectedStays}</p>
```

I need to get that `${selectedStays}` in jquery.

need suggestions if any

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`$('p.booking-desc').text()`

This will return the text whatever inside the `p` tag